# Меню действий по нажатию unity

Tags: unity3d, ui

я хочу чтоб по нажатию по объекту правой кнопкой там вызывалось меню действий. Я не знаю как это можно сделать помогите пожалуйста

Comment: Отследить нажатие правой кнопкой мыши по объекту -> вызвать меню действий. Гайдов о том как это сделать в интернете много.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Создаем первый скрипт:

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.Events;

public class Targeting : MonoBehaviour
{
    public UnityEvent<Target> OnTarget = new UnityEvent<Target>();
    public UnityEvent OnMiss = new UnityEvent();

    private Camera _camera;

    private void Awake()
    {
        _camera = Camera.main;
    }

    private void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(1))
        {
            TrySetTarget();
        }
    }

    private void TrySetTarget()
    {
        var ray = _camera.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition);

        if (Physics.Raycast(ray, out RaycastHit raycastHit) &&
            raycastHit.transform.TryGetComponent(out Target target))
        {
            OnTarget?.Invoke(target);
        }
        else
        {
            OnMiss?.Invoke();
        }
    }
}
```

Вешаем его на камеру:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Создаем второй скрипт:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Target : MonoBehaviour
{
    public List<ContextMenuAction> Actions => _actions;

    [SerializeField] private List<ContextMenuAction> _actions = new List<ContextMenuAction>();
}
```

вешаем на каждый объект, у которого хотите вызывать меню (допустим куб):
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

создаем третий скрипт:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.Events;

public class ContextMenu : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField] private Targeting _targeting;

    private List<ContextMenuAction> _currentActions = new List<ContextMenuAction>();

    private void Awake()
    {
        _targeting.OnTarget.AddListener(Show);
        _targeting.OnMiss.AddListener(Hide);

        gameObject.SetActive(false);
    }

    private void OnDestroy()
    {
        _targeting.OnTarget.RemoveListener(Show);
        _targeting.OnMiss.RemoveListener(Hide);
    }

    public void Show(Target target)
    {
        gameObject.SetActive(true);

        _currentActions = target.Actions;
        transform.position = Input.mousePosition;
    }

    public void Hide()
    {
        gameObject.SetActive(false);
    }
}

[System.Serializable]
public struct ContextMenuAction
{
    public string Name;
    public UnityEvent Action;
}
```

Этот скрипт вешаем на на UI панельку и даем ссылку на камеру:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Теперь для таргетов зададим список действий. Возьмем тот самый куб и добавим деактивацию коллайдера:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Теперь в при нажатии правой кнопкой мыши в контекстное меню передастся список структур, которые хранят название и событие действия. С вашей стороны необходимо создать список кнопок, где текст на кнопке и действие будет передаваться при каждом нажатии на объект, надеюсь вы с этим справитесь:)

Comment: Спасибо за помощь